# "something prevented the text engine from being initialized." in Photoshop CS5 portable

Tags: fonts, adobe-photoshop, portable

I'm using a portable installation of Photoshop CS5 Extended. Two days ago I did some animated gifs with text on them. I have not been using Photoshop much recently, but I had also done some work on text back in September without any problem.

Today I ran into the ["Could not complete your request because something prevented the text engine from being initialized."](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/troubleshoot-fonts-photoshop-cs5.html) error message. After a lot of searching, I managed to locate where the AdobeFnt_OSFonts.lst file was on my installation. Neither deleting it nor the entire folder has had any effect whatsoever.

I've checked in my font folder that none have been recently modified (and could have become corrupted), and nothing to report there. I've tried the FontTest script on the help page, but scripts are apparently nonfunctional on this installation (I have never needed to use one before).

Various windows update did come in on the 11th and today, but I have no idea why any of those could possibly affect Photoshop's text engine.

Is there anything at all I can possibly do short of figuring a way to reinstall the program?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on PS 2015 and here's how I solved it.

1. Go to c:\Windows\Fonts
2. Copy all fonts to another folder (I used c:\Windows\FontsTemp)
3. Delete all fonts in c:\Windows\Fonts
   It's OK that it doesn't let you delete required system fonts.
   Try photoshop. In my case, this made it work.
4. Then restore the fonts you want from your version of FontsTemp by copying them back into c:\Windows\Fonts.

Good luck!

Comment: Sadly that failed to have any effect whatsoever...